# postgresql - cannot switch into default user

Tags: sql, ubuntu, installation, crouton-os

I'm using a samsung chromebook and crouton to attempt to install pgsql on Ubuntu 12.04.

As root, I can excute the following command succesfully:

```
# sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

However when I try to switch users, the following occurs:

```
# sudo su - postgres
ln: failed to create symbolic link `/var/lib/postgresql/.pulse/default.pa': Permission denied
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried this: sudo postgresql-setup initdb; sudo service postgresql restart

Comment: Thanks for the reply - postgresql-setup doesn't appear to be a command.